# Ethernet jack pins are getting flat, how do I fix it?

Tags: connection, ethernet, repair

The pins on the Ethernet jack on my laptop are getting flat, and I'm worried about them eventually not connecting at all.  Is there some way I can pull them back out without risking damage, disassembling the computer, or sending it in for repair?